# How Do You Stack Instances on Z axis with Animation Nodes 2.0?

Tags: python, animation-nodes, instances

I'm relatively new to blender and extremely new to Animation Nodes 2.0. (I found out about it 2 days ago). I'm trying to make a cube falloff animation but I can only stack the cubes on the X and Y axis. I would like to stack the instances on the Z-axis and I'm stumped on how to accomplish it. I've rotated the object every which way to no avail. I've attached an image of my current workspace. Any ideas on how to get them stacked on the Z-axis? I'm scantily familiar with Python programming so please be kind to my confused brain with your answers! :-)

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: So you want a 3D grid? for objects to be distributed in all three directions?

Comment: Hi! I want to have the exact same effect as above (with my sphere controlling the falloff) however I want the cubes to be stacked on top of each other, like a wall. Since I'm using the animation nodes, I can't control the rotation in the 3D view as I normally could and I'm not sure which nodes to use to give me the functionally of flipping the whole grid up on the Z axis. ~Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Distribute Matrices Node](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/matrix/distribute_matrices.html) allows you to do exactly what you want:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!! One follow up question, if you don't mind. Is there a particular site where I can learn more about how to apply the nodes? I know the developer has a manual available but I'm finding it's more of a brief overview. Thanks again!