# Animation Nodes - Have an effector control the rotation of many objects

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to wrap my head around animation nodes, I have followed [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GF5krw0Z8QU) tutorial and it was easy to understand and do. However I am trying to do something a little different and I am completely lost.

In the attached picture all these objects are separated and put in a group. I would like to have my empty sphere control the rotation and falloff of each object. So I can show the tiles flipping over.

The above tutorial is only for making a grid from a single object, I don't need the grid and I have many objects. So I don't know how to convert this to what I need.

Any help with the node set up would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would of added my original node set up, but I would rather not be laughed off BSE. lol

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. You just want to rotate the tiles based on the falloff? Isn't that what he described in the tutorial?

Comment: Yes it is, but the problem I am having is he does it for a single object. I cant figure out how to get many objects to work. I tried "Objects from Group" node and "Objects list" node and it doesn't work the same. I am going to put a bounty in this in 30 minutes (have to wait the for the stupid bounty timer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Your Question

We can compose a transformation matrix out of the locations, then generate the rotation matrix using the Offset Matrices Node and then set the objects transformations to this new matrices.

[image: Node Tree]

**Warning** - Make sure not change the locations of the matrices or set the locations of the object by mistake to any value.

### Recommended

If your objects are exactly the same, then you can replicate them using the Object Instancer node and set their locations using thew Distribute matrices node (See my answer here: [Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91284/how-do-you-stack-instances-on-z-axis-with-animation-nodes-2-0/91486#91486)):

[image: Method 1]

**Note** - If the object has modifiers and you want to copy them, use Copy Full Object option in the Object Instancer.

If you objects are different, then you can replace the Object Instancer with the Object From Group just as you did.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't really understand AN and I was missing the "Compose Matrix" node (will research what this does). I knew someone would find this simple. I have a lot of learning to do. I will make sure I award the bounty but its making me wait 24 hours. I thought I had to use an "object transform output" node this whole time.